# Existence of a complete metric on $(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology

The question  is "Does  there  exist  a  complete  metric  on  $(0,1)$  that  induces  the  usual  topology?"

Now does complete  metric  on $(0,1)$ means $(0,1)$  is  complete  under  the  supposed  metric? If  two  metrics induces  the  same  topology  then  are  not  they   similar? Then  this , if  exists, will  be  similar to   the  euclidean metric but  $(0,1)$  is  not  complete  under  euclidean metric. So  such  a metric  does  not  exist. Or  have  I  got  the  question  totally  wrong? Does  it  mean something  other  than  what  I  assumed?

Comment: I cannot make heads or tails of your argument, because you have not defined 'similar'. There is indeed a complete metric on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller I think there a lot of complete metric spaces on $(0,1)$. For example on could be $[1/3, 1/2]$ and in general every closed subset of $(0, 1)$.

Comment: "Are there complete metric subspaces of $(0,1)$?" is not the question. The question is: is there a metric on $(0,1)$ that induces the standard topology such that this metric space is complete?

Comment: @MikeMiller  $c_{1} \rho(x,y)\le \delta(x,y)\le  c_{2} \rho(x,y)$  then  $\rho$  and  $\delta$  are  similar  metrics. for  $c_{1}$  and  $c_{2}$  scalars.

Comment: Completeness of a metric space is not a topological property. Two metrics which induce the same topology need not have the same metric structure. Consider a homeomorphism $h:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$. Then if $\rho$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb R$, $d(x,y)=\rho(h(x),h(y))$ is such a metric.

Comment: @user118494 Okay. In that case you're in trouble. I agree that if one of two similar metrics is not complete, then the other is not complete; but there's no reason for two different metrics that induce the same topology to be similar.

Answer (score 3):

For an explicit example of the sort that Alex S mentioned in the comments, consider $d(x,y)=|\tan(r(x))-\tan(r(y))|$, where $r(x)=\pi x - \pi/2$. This metric is complete because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete in its usual metric, and it induces the standard topology because $\tan \circ r$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does exist: if a space $(X,d)$ is homeomorphic with a complete metric space, then $X$ is topologically complete, i.e., there is a metric $d'$ in $X$ that generates the same topology as that generated by $d$ so that $(X,d')$ is complete. Since $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic with the Real line, the result applies here.