# Does such metrics exist?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In part of a theorem that I do not bother to mention 
 writer supposed that there are two metrics on (0,1) (called d ,D) such that set of all open sets of d is equal to set of all open sets of D and also (d,(0,1))
is complete while (D,(0,1)) is not complete.
 I ,  could not find any example for such metric spaces(d, D) I will appreciate if some one can give an example .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393254/existence-of-a-complete-metric-on-0-1?rq=1

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942217/does-such-a-metric-exist?rq=1